# Python - drawing a polygon

Tags: python

So I'm trying to draw different polygons using a point class. I've made a class called generate_polygon which is supposed to generate a regular polygon with s sides and x0, y0 is the starting vertex.

```
import sys
import math
import Line_Point 

try:
    x0 = float(sys.argv[1])
    y0 = float(sys.argv[2])
    s = int(sys.argv[3])
except:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Syntax: generate_polygon.py x0 y0 s'
    sys.exit(1)

p1 = Line_Point.Point(x0, y0)
while s>0:
    p2 = Line_Point.Point(p1.x, p1.y)
    p2.rotate((2*math.pi)/s)
    line = Line_Point.Line(p1, p2)
    print >> sys.stdout, line
    p1=p2
    s = s-1
```

It also uses another class called Line_Point:

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if not isinstance(x, float):
            raise Error("Parameter \"x\" illegal.")
        self.x = x
        if not isinstance(y, float):
            raise Error ("Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
        self.y = y

def rotate(self, a):
        if not isinstance(a, float):
            raise Error("Parameter \"a\" illegal.")
        original_x = self.x
        original_y = self.y  # not necessary but looks cleaner
        self.x = math.cos(a) * original_x - math.sin(a) * original_y
        self.y = math.sin(a) * original_x + math.cos(a) * original_y

class Line:

    def __init__(self, point0, point1):
        self.point0 = Point(point0.x, point0.y)
        self.point1 = Point(point1.x, point1.y)

    def rotate(self, a):
        if not isinstance(a, float) or not isinstance(self.point0.x, float) or not isinstance(self.point1.y, float):
        raise Error("Parameter \"a\" illegal.")
    self.point0.rotate(a)
    self.point1.rotate(a)
```

I'm also using another class called rotate which reads lines from stdin and splits them into 4 separate parts and rotates each part:

```
import sys
import Line_Point

try:
    a = float(sys.argv[1])
    count = int(sys.argv[2])
except:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Syntax: rotate.py angle count'
    sys.exit(1)
for L in sys.stdin:
    L = L.split()
    print L
    x0 = float(L[0])
    y0 = float(L[1])
    x = float(L[2])
    y = float(L[3])
    p0 = Line_Point.Point(x0, y0)
    p1 = Line_Point.Point(x, y)
    line = Line_Point.Line(p0, p1)
for x in range(count):
    print L
    p0.rotate(a)
```

So the expected output is a lines file with 4 different line parts. If I test the code using `python generate_polygon.py 0.0 250.0 3` then the expected output is:

```
line 0 250 -217 -125
line -217 -125 217 -125
line 217 -125 0 250
```

But what I end up getting is:

```
0 250 -217 -125
-217 -125 217 125
217 125 217 125
```

So several numbers are completely wrong and there's no line coming before the 4 lines. So I'm thinking the problem is either in my generate_polygon class or my rotate class but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: This is all very mysterious.  You do not show a class named Line_Point, nor a class named generate_polygon nor a class named rotate.  `.rotate()` is called as if it were a member of class Point, which it is not.  The output you give clearly cannot come from this collection of code.  What are you actually doing?

Comment: Well I'm not showing you every single bit of code in my classes. The Line_Point program is the code that contains the Point class and the Line class and the code is called Line_Point and that's why I'm calling that specific program. The first code was called generate_polygon.py. The second one was my Line_Point.py program. The third code was from my rotate.py program. I also have two other similar programs called scale and translate and they both work in a similar way to rotate.py. Do you understand now?

Comment: There is also a rotate inside my point class as well as another rotate.py program that I'm using which loops through each line in the stdin and splits each line into 4 sections.

Comment: The word `class` refers to a name that follows a class definition statement, in your case Point and Line.  The word `module` refers to a single .py file; modules are used with the `import` statement, in your case Line_Point.py.  In Python they are not the same thing at all (but they are in Java if I remember).  Using those terms correctly would have avoided miscommunication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the first function `rotate` belongs to the class `Point` and isn't indented correctly.  That's where the problem is.  The first line modifies the variable self.x and then the second line uses the already modified value.  You need this instead:

```
def rotate(self,a):
    original_x = self.x
    original_y = self.y  # not necessary but looks cleaner
    self.x = math.cos(a) * original_x - math.sin(a) * original_y
    self.y = math.sin(a) * original_x + math.cos(a) * original_y
```

Before the while loop in the top listing, `2*math.pi/s` is the angle to rotate each new line segment.  This angle shouldn't change during the calculation.  Since s is decremented each time through the loop, the angle should be computed before the loop is entered (that's a good practice anyway):

```
angle = 2 * math.pi / s
while s>0:
    p2 = Line_Point.Point(p1.x, p1.y)
    p2.rotate(angle)
    line = Line_Point.Line(p1, p2)
    print >> sys.stdout, line
    p1=p2
    s = s-1
```

Comment: If it's supposed to go in the point class then I'm 99% sure that's wrong. It needs to have 'a' passed in. The way it's called is  p0 = Point(0.0, 0.0)
 p0.rotate(1) where 1 is the angle it's being rotated by. I don't think you can make a rotate method with just self. It doesn't work. Also where does x and y come from? I already defined x and y above so there isn't any need to define those again.

Comment: Besides, even if I use your method and change it to (self, a), it still gives me the same output so in reality simply adding x = self.x doesn't need to do anything. I think the problem lies in another code.

Comment: I forgot the argument in my function, sorry to confuse things.  If the math relationship you want is (these are math equations, not python): `x' = sin(a)*x + cos(a)*y` and `y' = cos(a)*x + sin(a)*y` then that is NOT what your function does.  It actually calculates y' as cos(a)*x' + sin(a)*y; in other words, it uses the already modified x in line 2.  My function doesn't do that.  The two functions can't possibly give the same answer if a != 0.

Comment: What I actually want is x0 = cos(a) * x - sin(a) * y
y0 = sin(a) * x + cos(a) * y where the point (x0,y0) is the point (x,y) rotated counter-clockwise by theta radians. The reason I didn't use x0 and y0 is because the class has to print out the values of x and y and if I use x0 and y0 then x and y remain unchanged and the wrong value will be returned.

Comment: You are calling the new values x0 and y0 whereas I was calling them x' and y'.  What I'm trying to say is that you can't modify self.x in the first line and then use it in the second line AFTER you modified it.  That will cause you to get the wrong answer.  I realize that you want to keep the same variable names, so you have to create a temporary variable to hold on to the original value.  I called it just plain `x` the first time, but I modified my answer again to call it original_x.  I hope that makes my point clear.

Comment: Alright that helps a bit. I updated my code to show my new output. It's almost there except there's the word line that appears before the 4 values so I don't know how to add that but ignoring that for now, the first line is identical. For the second line, the last number is 125 and it needs to be -125. The last line also needs -125 as well as a 0 followed by 250. I'm getting 217 then 125.

Comment: Ok nvm about the word line that comes before the values, I figured out how to do that but I'm still getting the wrong values.

Comment: I found the other problem: as you decrement s in the while loop, the rotation angle changes.  See my amended solution.